# Inconveniente con cargue de registros en Combobox en Php con Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, php5

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirles el favor con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta trabajando en Php dentro de un hosting grauito
tengo el siguiente código para mostrar en un combobox el listado  de unos trabajos musicales que tengo en una base de datos Mysql:

```
<?php
   require('conexion.php');
$query1="Select Iddisco,Trabajo From discos ORDER BY Trabajo ASC";
$resultado1=$mysqli->query($query1);
?> 
<html>
    <head>
     <title> </title>
   <script  language="javascript" src="js/jquery-.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="combo" name="combo" method="POST">
        <div>Selecciona Trabajo:<select id="cbx_trabajo" name="cbx_trabajo"> 
            <option value="0">Seleccionar Trabajo</option>
             <?php WHILE($row1=$resultado1->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row['Iddisco']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Trabajo']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>  
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

pero al momento de correrlo me muestra tan solo el combobox, pero no los datos que son los trabajos musicales

Agradezco por la colaboración que me puedan brindar
Att. Hernán Martínez.

Comment: Tal vez se deba a que asignas los valores a $row1 pero intentas visualizarlos con $row.

Answer (score 1):

hazlo simplemente en un foreach para que recorras simplemente el array de datos

```
<?php
   require('conexion.php');
$query1="Select Iddisco,Trabajo From discos ORDER BY Trabajo ASC";
$resultado1=$mysqli->query($query1)->fetch_assoc();

?> 
<html>
    <head>
     <title> </title>
   <script  language="javascript" src="js/jquery-.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="combo" name="combo" method="POST">
        <div>Selecciona Trabajo:<select id="cbx_trabajo" name="cbx_trabajo"> 
            <option value="0">Seleccionar Trabajo</option>
             <?php   foreach ($resultado1 as $row) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row['Iddisco']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Trabajo']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>  
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

En caso tal de que no te funcione debes validar que tu variable $resultado1 si tiene datos

Comment: En caso de haber resultados, `fetch_assoc()` te va a devolver solo una fila, en todo caso, el método apropiado es [fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).